# Generically return array between cells with arrayformula?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

indirect and offset do not work properly with arrayformula, so for example

```
a
c
x
s
q
p
```

So I can use match or vlookup to find out that c is row 2 and q is row 5 but then I want to return an array of {c,x} it's pretty easy to accomplish with offset or indirect but how would you do it when it is an arrayformula (wanting to return multiple combinations) in one cell that can return everything between c and q and also between x and p, etc.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
=INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(MATCH(B1, A:A, 0), 1, 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(MATCH(B2, A:A, 0), 1, 4))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have posted a more specific example, I was just inspired of this question from reading some of the more recent questions so I didn't have an exact sheet, but I want to take that example you just made but apply it to ArrayFormula so that you can have x and p as well as c and q. I don't think indirect can be used to do that with ArrayFormula.

Comment: it rly depends on how the dataset looks like and how you wish the output should look like

Comment: I saw your recent answer on the days between dates with arrayformula, I was in the middle of a solution as well but suddenly realized even with a helper column I couldn't generically return a subset of an array with an arrayformula at least to my knowledge. So basically the example you produced but with the added arrayformula component that generically works. So for example you demonstrate clearly how to do it without arrayformula, now add a second criteria input... you can't really do it right because indirect and offset do not support it? But thinking of universal alternative

Comment: like I said, it depends on dataset... that post with days between days was numeric so all that was needed was to generate numbers from 0 to whatever the day difference was for each row and then just sum the starting day with this generated array. if dataset is not numeric than we would need to translate it into ROW terms and then just overlay it with the sequence from column A

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to do this using hlookup.

Are you asking if given 2 and 5, can you pull {c,x} in a single array formula?

Comment: I'm saying with one formula return the array {c,x} but also {s,q} basically I have no problem returning one array but what if I wanted to return multiple arrays with one formula.

Comment: For your example, try this formula...
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP("X",{"X";A1:A},{2,3;4,5},0))

Comment: Ahh, but how would you use this if you didn't know the amount of cells between the two values? Probably you should include some match formulas to make it a full solution.

Comment: Maybe. I think I just need to understand the real goal. Something that's an actual example?  Maybe you could mock up a use case?

Comment: searching c,q and x,p but having a random and unknown list in column A sort of like in the original question I think is the best example, it's more of a generic problem solving method your hlookup was really close until I realized it didn't really work for ranges more than 2.

Comment: Ok.  I will mock something up here that i think will work for you.  I will add it as a separate answer since I now have a slightly different understanding of the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204688/discussion-between-mattking-and-codecamper).

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the problem a little better,  I thought I might offer this sample sheet as a potential option.  The single arrayformula is in cell E2. Feel free to make a new tab to re-state the problem if i still don't quite understand it.

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mgZRzk0xGFXS1yIs0aIau15sENZn_fUuunjTEKCq16g/edit?usp=sharing)

Cheers,
Matt